# Split the terminal into multiple, and call program on each

Tags: c, shell, gnu-screen

I have a C program where I would like to have 2 console opened. One where I would show a map, and the other one a chat.

Right now, I'm running the program on the console (where the map is showing), and I'm opening a second console with this :

```
system("xterm ./chat +hold -geometry 60x40+1400+450 -title 'Chat' &");
```

But this looks horrible, so I would like use gnu-screen to have 2 console side by side.

How can I do it ?

Comment: it is not cler what you are asking for, and even less clear why you want to do this. You're going to get better help if you explain what the end requirement is...

Comment: Edited the main post, tell me if it is clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following

```
xterm -geometry 132x50+10+30 -e 'screen -c ./my_special_screenrc'
```

the `./my_special_screenrc` should contain

```
screen -t map  1 ./map     #run the "map" command
screen -t chat 2 ./chat    #run the "chat" command
split
select 1 #the map - defined above
focus
select 2 #the chat
```

tested with the following, `./map` command

```
while :
do
    echo "This is the $0 program"
    sleep 5
done
```

and similar for the chat `ln map chat`.

In the upper half prints every 5 second

```
This is the ./map program
This is the ./map program
```

in the lower half

```
This is the ./chat program
```